# ScalaFX: Is it possible to define controls in objects other than the application object?

Tags: controls, scalafx

What I am trying to accomplish is: having a *ScalaFX* application with some nice ordered `object`s called `Buttons`, `Labels`, `Checkboxes` and so on to keep everything nice and in order.

Here a little example to show what I mean:

```scala
package ButtonsAndLabel

import scalafx.Includes._
import scalafx.application.JFXApp
import scalafx.scene.Scene
import scalafx.scene.control.{ Button, Label }
import scalafx.event.ActionEvent

object Main extends JFXApp {

  stage = new JFXApp.PrimaryStage {
    title = "Test-Program"

    scene = new Scene(300, 200) {
      val label = new Label("Nothing happened yet") {
        layoutX = 20
        layoutY = 20
      }
      val button1 = new Button("Button 1") {
        layoutX = 20
        layoutY = 50
        onAction = (e: ActionEvent) => {
          label.text = "B1 klicked"
        }
      }
      val button2 = new Button("Button 2") {
        layoutX = 20
        layoutY = 80
        onAction = (e: ActionEvent) => {
          label.text = "B2 klicked"
        }
      }

      content = List(label, button1, button2)
    }
  }
}
```

This code shows a window with a label and two buttons, and the buttons change the text of the label.

That works fine.

But when my code grows with a lot more controls, things get messy.

That's why I tried to transfer the controls into other `object`s (in different files). I've put the label into an object called `Labels`:

```scala
package ButtonsAndLabel

import scalafx.scene.control.Label
import scalafx.event.ActionEvent

object Labels {
  val label = new Label("Nothing happened yet") {
    layoutX = 20
    layoutY = 20
  }
}
```

when I import this into the main-file with

```scala
import Labels.label
```

everything works fine.

But then I try to put the buttons into a `Buttons` object:

```scala
package ButtonsAndLabel

import scalafx.scene.control.Button
import scalafx.event.ActionEvent
import Labels.label

object Buttons {
  val button1 = new Button("Button 1") {
    layoutX = 20
    layoutY = 50
    onAction = (e: ActionEvent) => {
      label.text = "B1 klicked"
    }
  }
  val button2 = new Button("Button 2") {
    layoutX = 20
    layoutY = 80
    onAction = (e: ActionEvent) => {
      label.text = "B2 klicked"
    }
  }
}
```

this brings the error message when I try to compile:

> ```scala
> [error]  found   : scalafx.event.ActionEvent => Unit
> [error]  required: javafx.event.EventHandler[javafx.event.ActionEvent]
> [error]     onAction = (e: ActionEvent) => {
> ```

and now I am stuck, as I don't know any *Java*.

Does anybody know if it is even possible what I am trying to do?

So far I have not found anything about this on the net. The problem doesn't keep me from writing the program I want, but the last application I wrote was a real mess with all the controls in one file.

Am I overlooking something obvious here?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your approach is perfectly OK.

The error you're seeing actually has nothing to do with *Java*—it's output by the *Scala* compiler! All it's saying is that it has been supplied one type of element (in this case, a function that takes a `scalafx.event.ActionEvent` and that returns `Unit`) when it was expecting another type of element (a `javafx.event.EventHandler[javafx.event.ActionEvent]` instance, in this case).

*ScalaFX* is just a set of *Scala*-friendly wrappers for the *JavaFX* library; without the `implicit` conversion functions that convert between the two sets of elements, the *Scala* compiler will complain about finding *ScalaFX* elements when it needs *JavaFX* elements, and *vice versa*.

The solution is to ensure that the following `import` is added to each of your *ScalaFX* source files:

```scala
import scalafx.Includes._
```

(You have this at the top of your main source file, but not the others.)

This will ensure that your *ScalaFX* `ActionEvent` handler is converted into the *JavaFX* equivalent, thereby making your life a little easier.

This is a very common type of error with *ScalaFX*, which is nearly always fixed by specifying the above `import`. (If the `import` doesn't fix your problem, then you will typically have a genuine case of type confusion, in which you just plain used the wrong type of object.)

So, here's what I think your code needs to look like:

`Main.scala`:

```scala
import scalafx.Includes._
import scalafx.application.JFXApp
import scalafx.scene.Scene
import buttonsandlabel._

object Main extends JFXApp {

  stage = new JFXApp.PrimaryStage {
    title = "Test-Program"

    scene = new Scene(300, 200) {
      content = List(Labels.label, Buttons.button1, Buttons.button2)
    }
  }
}
```

`buttonsandlabel/Labels.scala`:

```scala
package buttonsandlabel

import scalafx.Includes._
import scalafx.scene.control.Label

object Labels {
  val label = new Label("Nothing happened yet") {
    layoutX = 20
    layoutY = 20
  }
}
```

`buttonsandlabel/Buttons.scala`:

```scala
package buttonsandlabel

import scalafx.Includes._
import scalafx.scene.control.Button
import scalafx.event.ActionEvent
import Labels.label

object Buttons {
  val button1 = new Button("Button 1") {
    layoutX = 20
    layoutY = 50
    onAction = (e: ActionEvent) => {
      label.text = "B1 klicked"
    }
  }
  val button2 = new Button("Button 2") {
    layoutX = 20
    layoutY = 80
    onAction = (e: ActionEvent) => {
      label.text = "B2 klicked"
    }
  }
}
```

(Note that package names, by convention, are typically all lowercase.)

One thing that you'll need to be aware of is the *JavaFX Application Thread*: all of your code that interacts with *ScalaFX* (or *JavaFX*) must execute on this thread. If you access *ScalaFX*/*JavaFX* from a different thread, you'll get an error exception. (This ensures that all such applications are *thread-safe*.) If you're unfamiliar with multi-threading, don't worry, *ScalaFX* initializes your application in such a way that this is fairly trivial. Usually, all that's needed is that your initialization code goes into your main application object's constructor (the object that extends `JFXApp`).

When you start creating *ScalaFX* elements in other classes and objects, you need to take extra care. An `object` is initialized when first referenced. If it is first referenced by code that is *not* executing on the *JavaFX Application Thread*, then you'll get thread error exceptions. One possible option is to put such code into `def` or `lazy val` members, so that they are only executed when referenced directly.

Alternatively, you may have to invoke your code via `scalafx.application.Platform.runLater()`.

For more information on the *JavaFX Application Thread*, refer to the [*JavaFX* documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much for that! I just tried it out and it works perfectly. Such a simple thing, but if you don't know it it is hard to find out. Again, Thank's a lot.